# Amazon SES -> SNS SQS notifications not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, email-bounces

I have a customer who has his own AWS/SES account to send emails using SES.

We have our own AWS account to host our servers and to use SNS/SQS.

We setup **his** SES verified sender email to send SNS notifications about Bounces and Complaints to **our** SNS Topic, and subscribed **our** SQS Queue to **our** SNS Topic.

We thought everything was working fine, we even received a message in our queues (one for bounces, another for complaints) about SES setup subscription.

The problem is, we haven't received the notifications.
We receive those notification by email, but no notification is arriving in our SQS Queue at all.

If I send a test bounce from Console Panel to bounce@simulator.amazonses.com or complaint@simulator.amazonses.com from my client account Console Panel, I receive a new SQS notification in my (account) queue with the bounced message, but I still won't receive the real bounces/complaints.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found out.

We were sending the emails from email address "A" and setting a reply-to to email address "B".

**All** bounce notifications are sent to the reply-to address... once we setup SNS/SQS notifications to the reply-to address, notifications started flowing.

Comment: you saved my day! A bit confusing to also specify this per email address, but it makes sense.

Comment: DOH!!!! Amazing catch! I can stop swearing now.